# How to launch activity from quickaction?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, popup

I have a custom popup window (quick action) in my app using [this project](http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/). I want to start activity after clicking on the button (in this popup window). Here is the code of activity with popup:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView popupButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.popup_btn);
    popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupWindow dw = new PopupWindow(v);
            dw.showLikePopDownMenu();
        }
    });
}

    // my stuff



//popup window
private class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements OnClickListener {
    public PopupWindow(View anchor) {
        super(anchor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        // inflate layout
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) this.anchor.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

        // setup button events
        ImageView aboutButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.setContentView(root);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_about: {
        Intent activity = new Intent(FistActivity.this, About.class);
        startActivity(activity);
        break;
        }

    }
}}
```

But this method of launching activity from popup doesn't work.
Here is another version of the code (in source PopupWindow was private *static* class):

private static class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements OnClickListener {
        public PopupWindow(View anchor) {
        super(anchor);
    }

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    // inflate layout
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) this.anchor.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    // setup button events
    ImageView aboutButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    this.setContentView(root);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_about: {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, About.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }
}}
```

eclipse says that at first I should delete *static* from `private static class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements...`, then I have following for `intent.setClass(this, About.class);`:

```
The method setClass(Context, Class<?>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (FirstActivity.PopupWindow, Class<About>).
```

Please, help to solve this problem.

---

**Added Log.** When I'm pressing button to open popup window app force closes with following log:

```
03-09 21:37:18.259: D/AndroidRuntime(9037): Shutting down VM
03-09 21:37:18.259: W/dalvikvm(9037): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.example.FirstActivity$PopupWindow.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:118)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.example.PopupWindowActivity.<init>(PopupWindowActivity.java:52)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.example.FirstActivity$PopupWindow.<init>(FirstActivity.java:103)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.example.FirstActivity$1.onClick(FirstActivity.java:32)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-09 21:37:18.259: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to have context passed into your intent. Try passing the context into your popupwindowactivity by creating a constructor that accepts Context as one of the parameters

Ex.

```
private static class PopupWindow extends PopupWindowActivity implements OnClickListener { 
    private Context context; //you now have access to context!

    public PopupWindow(View anchor, Context context) { //new constructor
    super(anchor); 
    this.context = context; //notice this!

    }

@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    // inflate layout
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) this.anchor.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    // setup button events
    ImageView searchButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
    algebraButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    this.setContentView(root);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_about: {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(context, About.class); //using the context down here!!

        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }
}}
```

Notice the code 
intent.setClass(context, About.class); 
which makes use of the context that you passed in

Comment: Thanks for that, but now I've got error here `likemenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    PopupWindow dw = new PopupWindow(v);
    dw.showLikePopDownMenu();
   }` The constructor FirstActivity.PopupWindow(View) is undefined

Comment: You need to pass the context into the constructor. Change it to this: PopupWindow dw = new PopupWindow(v, this);

Comment: Now I've got `The constructor FirstActivity.PopupWindow(View, new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`

Comment: Sorry, it should have been: PopupWindow dw = new PopupWindow(v, FirstActivity.this);

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve my problem, but when I'm pressing button to open popup window app force closes. I added log in question. Please, look.